# How to get a T-SQL query with views replaced with their definitions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with BI database where some  of the queries access many views, and the views in turn query from other views. Some queries have 3-4 levels of views, which turns debugging performance into nightmare.

Is there a way to "flatten" all views in an SQL query, replacing them with their definitions? I would use such queries to debug performance issues and fix them in their respective view definitions, and to explore a data model I am not yet fully familiar with.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
-- Original query
SELECT v1.foo
    ,v1.bar
FROM view1 v1

-- view1
CREATE VIEW view1
AS
SELECT v2.baz AS foo
    ,v2.boom AS bar
FROM view2 v2

-- view2
CREATE VIEW view2
AS
SELECT baz,
     boom
FROM footable

-- Desired query
SELECT view1.foo
    ,view1.bar
FROM (
    SELECT view2.baz AS foo
        ,view2.boom AS bar
    FROM (
        SELECT baz
            ,boom
        FROM footable
        ) view2
    ) view1
```

Comment: You could use nested subqueries as the last one you do. You can also use CTEs to encapsulate your different queries (they almost works as views) Or even better your can use temporary tables which you also can index to gain performance

Comment: The schema is already in place and the queries are already written. Unfortunately, getting rid of the views is not an option.

Comment: See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven